# How do I make my application responsive during Entity Framework operations?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have a fairly simple WPF application that uses Entity Framework. The main page of the application has a list of records that I am getting from a database on startup.

Each record has a picture, so the operation can be a little slow when the wireless signal is poor. I'd like this (and many of my SQL operations) to perform in the background if possible. I have async/await setup and at first it seemed to be working exactly as I wanted but now I'm seeing that my application is becoming unresponsive when accessing the DB.

Eventually I'm thinking I'm going to load up the text in one query and the images in another background operation and load them as they come in. This way I get the important stuff right away and the pictures can come in in the background, but the way things are going it's still looking like it will lock up if I do this.

On top of that, I'm trying to implement something to handle connectivity issues (in case the wifi cuts out momentarily) so that the application notifies the user of a connection issue, automatically retries a few times, etc. I put a try catch for SQL exception which seems to be working for me, but the whole application locks up for about a minute while it is trying to connect to the DB.

I tried testing my async/await using `await Task.Delay()` and everything is very responsive as expected while awaiting the delay, but everything locks up when awaiting the `.ToListAsync()`. Is this normal and expected? My understanding of async/await is pretty limited.

My code is kind of messy (I'm new) but it does what I need it to do for the most part. I understand there's probably plenty of improvements I can make and better ways to do things, but one step at a time here. My main goal right now is to keep the application from crashing during database accessing exceptions and to keep the user notified of what the application is doing (searching, trying to access db, unable to reach DB and retrying, etc) as opposed to being frozen, which is what they're going to think when they see it being unresponsive for over a minute.

Some of my code:

In my main view model

```
DataHelper data = new DataHelper();
private async void GetQualityRegisterQueueAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var task = data.GetQualityRegisterAsync();
            IsSearching = true;
            await task;
            IsSearching = false;
            QualityRegisterItems = new ObservableCollection<QualityRegisterQueue>(task.Result);
            OrderQualityRegisterItems();
        }
        catch (M1Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("QualityRegisterLogViewModel.GetQualityRegisterQueue() Operation Failed");
        }

    }
```

My Data Helper Class

```
public class DataHelper
{

    private bool debugging = false;

    private const int MAX_RETRY = 2;
    private const double LONG_WAIT_SECONDS = 5;
    private const double SHORT_WAIT_SECONDS = 0.5;
    private static readonly TimeSpan longWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LONG_WAIT_SECONDS);
    private static readonly TimeSpan shortWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SHORT_WAIT_SECONDS);
    private enum RetryableSqlErrors
    {
        ServerNotFound = -1,
        Timeout = -2,
        NoLock = 1204,
        Deadlock = 1205,
    }

    public async   Task<List<QualityRegisterQueue>> GetQualityRegisterAsync()
    {
       if(debugging) await Task.Delay(5000);

       var retryCount = 0;
       using (M1Context m1 = new M1Context())
       {
           for (; ; )
           {
               try
               {
                   return await (from a in m1.QualityRegisters
                                 where (a.qanClosed == 0)
                                 //orderby a.qanAssignedDate descending, a.qanOpenedDate
                                 orderby a.qanAssignedDate.HasValue descending, a.qanAssignedDate, a.qanOpenedDate
                                 select new QualityRegisterQueue
                                 {
                                     QualityRegisterID = a.qanQualityRegisterID,
                                     JobID = a.qanJobID.Trim(),
                                     JobAssemblyID = a.qanJobAssemblyID,
                                     JobOperationID = a.qanJobOperationID,
                                     PartID = a.qanPartID.Trim(),
                                     PartRevisionID = a.qanPartRevisionID.Trim(),
                                     PartShortDescription = a.qanPartShortDescription.Trim(),
                                     OpenedByEmployeeID = a.qanOpenedByEmployeeID.Trim(),
                                     OpenedByEmployeeName = a.OpenedEmployee.lmeEmployeeName.Trim(),
                                     OpenedDate = a.qanOpenedDate,
                                     PartImage = a.JobAssembly.ujmaPartImage,
                                     AssignedDate = a.qanAssignedDate,
                                     AssignedToEmployeeID = a.qanAssignedToEmployeeID.Trim(),
                                     AssignedToEmployeeName = a.AssignedEmployee.lmeEmployeeName.Trim()
                                 }).ToListAsync();
               }
               catch (SqlException ex)
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine("SQL Exception number = " + ex.Number);
                   if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RetryableSqlErrors), ex.Number))
                       throw new M1Exception(ex.Message, ex);

                   retryCount++;

                   if (retryCount > MAX_RETRY) throw new M1Exception(ex.Message, ex); ;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Retrying. Count = " + retryCount);
                   Thread.Sleep(ex.Number == (int)RetryableSqlErrors.Timeout ?
                                                           longWait : shortWait);
               }
           }
       }


    }


}
```

Edit: Mostly looking for general guidance here, though a specific example of what to do would be great.  For these types of operations where I am downloading data, is it just a given that if I need the application to be responsive I need to be making multiple threads?  Is that a common solution to this type of problem?  Is this not something I should be expecting async/await to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you call this method from your UI thread, you will overload the capture of UI thread context and back on itself. Also, your service will not be necessarily "Performant" because it must wait until the UI thread is free before it can continue.

The solution is simple: just call the method passing the ConfigureAwait "false" parameter when you made the call.

```
.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwaiter(false);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I gave this a try in both my ViewModel and my DataHelper but it didn't seem to change anything.